# Ember: Best practices with Selenium to make integration tests in browser

Tags: selenium, ember.js

Have you any experiences/examples to make Selenium tests with ember.js?

I cannot "grab" views (I use router), because they have not-deterministic ids.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own id's for view elements explicitly. Directly from handlebars like:

```
{{#view Ember.TextField elementId="my_id"}}
```

Or from your view object:

```
MyApp.MyView = Ember.View.Extend({
  elemntId: "my_id"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[EmberJS](https://emberjs.com/) generates/assigns dynamic values for `id` attributes, example, `ember32`, `ember33`, `ember34`, etc. In these cases you won't be able to use the full value of the `id` attribute to locate/click the elements. As an example, consider the following element:

```
<input placeholder="" id="ember32" class="ssRegistrationField ssEmailTextboxField ember-text-field ember-view" type="email">
```

The value of the value of the `id` attribute will keep changing dynamically, everytime you access the *AUT(Application Under Test)*. Hence to interact / click those elements, the solution is to construct **dynamic** [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as `visibilityOfElementLocated()` as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.ssRegistrationField.ssEmailTextboxField.ember-text-field.ember-view[id^='ember']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'ember') and @class='ssRegistrationField ssEmailTextboxField ember-text-field ember-view']"))).click();
  ```