# How to match regex in xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

I need to match `//*[@id="ember140"]` xpath for selenium.
Can someone provide me any solution as how to match any regular expression that starts with `@id="ember*****"` that is anything followed by ember.

I tried

```
checker = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'ember')")
```

It didn't work.

Comment: //*[contains(@id, "ember")]  will match anything that's contains (not just starts)

Comment: When you say "it didn't work" especially after trying the advice of people who spend time helping you please put some effort to explain what exactly you mean when say "didn't work". Either it finds element that you do not expect or it finds no elements.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933422/ember-best-practices-with-selenium-to-make-integration-tests-in-browser/60547527#60547527), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276695/selenium-finding-element-based-on-ember/59282757#59282757), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653659/ember-dropdown-selenium-xpath/60548670#60548670) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026817/automate-ember-js-application-using-selenium-when-object-properties-are-changed/60546822#60546822) discussion help you?

Answer (score 1):

Your Xpath seems wrong.Try this

```
checker = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'ember')]")
```