# Click on ember.js enabled element using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, ember.js, css-selectors

I am trying to click on the following button on a linkedin page using `selenium`:

```
<button id="ember607" class="share-actions__primary-action artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view" data-control-name="share.post"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    
        Post
    
</span></button>
```

I have tried to use:

- `driver.find_element_by_id`, but the id of the button seems to keep changing number
- `driver.find_element_by_xpath`, but this contains the button number, so also fails
- `driver.find_element_by_class_name('share-actions__primary-action artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view')`, this fails even though the class name is correct ?

Basically, all methods generate the same error message:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:{[*the_error_is_here*]}
```

I have also tried the xpath contains() method, but this does not find the button.

What would be the correct way to click on this button please ?

I am using python version `3.9` on `windows` with `driver = webdriver.Chrome`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is an [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element. So to `click()` on the element with text as **Post** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.share-actions__primary-action[data-control-name='share.post']>span.artdeco-button__text").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'share-actions__primary-action') and @data-control-name='share.post']/span[@class='artdeco-button__text' and contains(., 'Post')]").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.share-actions__primary-action[data-control-name='share.post']>span.artdeco-button__text"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'share-actions__primary-action') and @data-control-name='share.post']/span[contains(., 'Post')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium - Finding element based on ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276695/selenium-finding-element-based-on-ember/59282757#59282757)
- [Automate Ember.js application using Selenium when object properties are changed at run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026817/automate-ember-js-application-using-selenium-when-object-properties-are-changed/60546822#60546822)
- [Ember: Best practices with Selenium to make integration tests in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933422/ember-best-practices-with-selenium-to-make-integration-tests-in-browser/60547527#60547527)
- [Ember dropdown selenium xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653659/ember-dropdown-selenium-xpath/60548670#60548670)

Comment: this works:   `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'share-actions__primary-action') and @data-control-name='share.post']/span[contains(., 'Post')]"))).click()` with the imports as above.   Thanks

Comment: you are welcome,  please upvote the question if you think it is helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there are problems with buttons that are not clickable at the moment.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '[YOUR X_PATH TO THE BUTTON]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", button)
```

It's not the cleanest way to click any Button with selenium, but for me this method works mostly everytime.

Comment: I upvoted this because whilst the answer was not the accepted answer, it was helpful in getting the solution, which used similar techniques `expected_conditions`, `WebDriverWait` and `By`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//button[@class="share-actions__primary-action artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view"].
```

Or

```
//button[contains(@id,'ember')]
```

Comment: do you mean put this into xpath like this:   `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="share-actions__primary-action artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view"]')`.  If so this returns the same error message.

Comment: Cannot use the `//button[contains(@id,'ember')]` suggestion as there are *many* buttons wth `ember`+`some_random_number`.

Comment: Try using explicit wait with the first xpath then

Answer (score 0):

By xpath this should work:

```
//button/span[contains(text(), "Post")]
```

Combine it with a wait for the element:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button/span[contains(text(), "Post")]"))
    )
```

The problem with your by class selectors is the multiple class names. See this question: [How to get elements with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184562/how-to-get-elements-with-multiple-classes/7184581) for more details on how to overcome that.

Comment: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button/span[contains(text(), 'Post')]"}`....

Comment: and does it work if you add a wait (i've edited answer)

Comment: no, it gives a different error:   `Exception has occurred: TypeError
__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`.  note: i corrected one set of single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: I had a typo. Updated for you.

Comment: still gives `Exception has occurred: TypeError
__init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: Sorry, I think i need more context to where that error is happening

Answer (score 0):

Find the span with Post and click it's button tag.

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Post')]/parent::button
```

Comment: i do this `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Post')]/parent::button").click()` but get this error `Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(), 'Post')]/parent::button"}`