# Accepting cookies while scraping page with requests and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I did a script that tracks the price of a product on many different pages.
The problem is that some websites uses cookies and you have to click accept cookies to see the price.

This will probably not help but [this](https://www.power.se/) is the website it's in swedish so many of you won't understand.

How do I accept cookies while web scraping?

Answer (score 0):

There are no cookies being involved in doing a request.
I feel you shouldn't be facing any problem doing a get or a post request.

Edit:
try this peice of code:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')

with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(r.text)
    f.close()
```

Run the `test.html` file in your web browser and try to see the difference.
The `test.html` is what your code sees which is different from what a normal person sees in their web browser with the full GUI.

Comment: I just guessed this was the problem but I may be wrong. This is my second python script so I don't have much knowledge

Comment: Its Okay, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you scrape a site you don't have to accept those cookies.
But if you want to accept then you can simply click on the "accept-button" from the website.
You can do this with this method:

- [Clicking with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65161055/14770638)

Get the X-Path with right clicking on the website and inspect the cookie button.